# Set Hyperlink Address for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in my workbook. Names are as follows:

```
1) Temp
2) Validation Report
```

Sheet "Temp" contains 10000 rows in column 'A'.

Sheet "Validation Report" contains 3 columns 'A', 'B' and 'C', for error reporting. Error rows are populated for empty cell values present in Sheet "Temp". Column 'A' contains 'Name of Sheet "Temp"', Column 'B' contains value of empty cell of sheet "Temp" with a hyperlink to the appropriate cell, Column 'C' contains the error message.

I am using following macro to detect empty cells in sheet "Temp" and show error message for those cells in sheet "Validation Report" and provide hyperlinks to the appropriate cells of sheet "Temp".

```
Dim validationErrors(1 To 20000, 1 To 3) As Variant
Dim hyperlinkSubaddress(1 To 20000) As Variant
dat = Range("A1:A10000").Value

validationSheetStartRow = 0
c = 1

startTime = Timer

Do While (c < 10000)

    num = dat(c, 1)

    errorMsg = "Value is not present."
    If (IsEmpty(Sheets("Temp").Cells(c, 1))) Then
        validationSheetStartRow = validationSheetStartRow + 1
        validationErrors(validationSheetStartRow, 1) = "Temp"
        validationErrors(validationSheetStartRow, 2) = num
        validationErrors(validationSheetStartRow, 3) = errorMsg
        hyperlinkSubaddress(validationSheetStartRow) = "Temp!" & Sheets("Temp").Cells(c, 1).Address
    End If

    c = c + 1
Loop


Sheets(validationErrorSheet).Range("A1:C" & validationSheetStartRow) = validationErrors
Sheets(validationErrorSheet).Range("A1:A" & validationSheetStartRow).Hyperlink.SubAddress = hyperlinkSubaddress

endTime = Timer

MsgBox endTime - startTime
```

The following line in the above code is written to set the sub-address for hyperlinks:

```
Sheets(validationErrorSheet).Range("A1:A" & validationSheetStartRow).Hyperlink.SubAddress = hyperlinkSubaddress
```

It gives the following error:

> Run-Time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

Is there a way we can set the hyperlinks to a range in a fast way?

Comment: `hyperlinkSubaddress` is defined as array so you need to give an index like `hyperlinkSubaddress(index)`. You cannot set an array for `.SubAddress` it awaits a string ([see documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/hyperlink-subaddress-property-excel)) If you want to set a different hyperlink for each cell in a range then you would need to loop through that range.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: We have those stored in an array. Is there a way to do it in single line by using some excel functions instead of a loop?

Comment: No. As I wrote you will need to loop because the `.SubAddress` only accepts a string as parameter and no array.

Comment: @saint1729 Agree with PEH, you'll have to loop through the cells

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , absinthe It's taking 3-4 seconds for the loop get executed for populating links to 10000 rows in Validation Report. I followed something like the one mentioned here. https://niallflynn.com/news/convert-urls-to-clickable-links-in-excel/ Can this be optimized?

Comment: If your code works and doesn't show any errors and you just ask "*Can this be optimized?*" then this might be a question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But let me just say: A loop is a loop and it needs it's time to loop through and populate 10000 rows with links. What you can try is turn of screen updating before the task `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and turn on again after the task.